# Can't manage to edit class from css

Tags: css, wordpress

So I'm working on a website from someone.

It has the following lines of code.

```
<div class="parallax image-container anim-css" style="background-image: url("image_url"); 
            background-position: 50% 0px;"></div>
```

So I can't manage to change that image url from the css, someone any idea?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Remove the inline style attribute, fix your quotes and you will be fine.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto It's on wordpress and I can't find the correct php file. It's a bought theme I think and it's very bad. So I don't know how the edit the html.

Comment: If you bought it then ask for some help from the guys who sold you.

Answer (score 0):

That because you have inline style in your tag and it have a priority more than class, also you've a quotes problem you should use sigle quotes `'` :

```
<div ..."background-image: url('http://lifehacking.nl/wp-content/uploads/google-logo.jpg'); background-position: 50% 0px;"></div>
_______________________________^________________________________________________________^
```

You could use `!important` to force class image instead :

```
.new-image{
    background-image: url('http://bit.do/logo124578') !important; 
}
```

But it's not a good practice, you may have to toggle between to classes when you want to change `background-image` and remove inline style at all like :

```
.old-image{
    background-image: url('old_img_url') !important; 
}

.new-image{
    background-image: url('new_img_url') !important; 
}

<div class="parallax image-container anim-css old-image"></div>
<div class="parallax image-container anim-css new-image"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What should be the correct css handling for the image akhi?

Comment: It's on wordpress and I can't find the correct php file. It's a bought theme I think and it's very bad. So I don't know how the edit the html.

Comment: Ok you have two choices if you could reach the css file then change it using `!important` (or just create your own class and toggle between them check my updated answer) else you could change the background from inline code..